# Reading and updating Gradle build files and Android activities from an Android Studio/IntelliJ plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, android-studio-plugin

I’m working on an Android Studio plugin that integrates an SDK to Android app. Similar to what [Fabric.io](https://fabric.io/downloads/android-studio) do.

I was able to follow the documentation to create a simple plugin, I’m now trying to read the Gradle build file and the activity file and dependency add code to the project, how can I achieve this?

*Note: Any pointers or example projects will be helpful, I tried to look at example projects but the only interesting thing I found is some plugins are using this package `com.android.tools.idea.gradle` but not sure where these APIs are publicly documented.*

Edit:

I found more info, the package I mentioned above is the IDE `Android Plugin` I could also use some of its method if I added the jar in my project. I still have problem running the code, will update if I found out why it's breaking.